# How to make sure that click handler is only registered once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
function expandCollapse(hypId, ElemId, ShowText, HideText) {
    var handler = function () {
        $("#" + ElemId).toggle();
        toggle(hypId, ElemId, ShowText, HideText);
    }

    $('#' + hypId).live('click', handler);

}
```

I want to make sure that no matter if this code is called for >1 time, it shouldn't do anything as long as the same hypId is being registered for click event. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things:

1: You shouldn't be using `live()`, it's [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/).

2: The easiest way to handle this kind of situation (if the element is around when you do the expand/collapse) is to use namespacing. So like this:

```
function expandCollapse(hypId, ElemId, ShowText, HideText) {
    var handler = function () {
        $("#" + ElemId).toggle();
        toggle(hypId, ElemId, ShowText, HideText);
    }

    $('#' + hypId).off('click.mynamespace').on('click.mynamespace', handler);
}
```

Replace `mynamespace` with something of your choosing that's relevant to the handler in question. That way, it will remove any existing handlers that it might have attached before re-adding the handler with the new options [without impacting any other handlers](http://api.jquery.com/on/) that might be in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#' + hypId).one('click', handler);
```